# How to escape special characters in password?

Tags: command-line

I am trying to install SVN in Ubuntu. My network proxy has a password. In `apt.conf` when i do:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:pass@word@proxy_server:proxy_port";
```

It's not working . My question is how can I escape @ in pass@word?
I tried many combinations but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try using single quotes around it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need escape the first `@`  With `\` or use use its Hex ASCII value `%40`

Try:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:pass\@word@proxy_server:proxy_port";
```

or

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:pass%40word@proxy_server:proxy_port";
```